# How to update combo box using data binding in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Hello I am looking at data binding in a winform application.

I have two classes: employee and job defined as below.

```
public class Employee
{

    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int Id { set; get; }

    public Employee(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }

}


public class Job
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public Employee Employee { set; get; }

    public Job(string name, Employee employee)
    {
        Name = name;
        Employee = employee;
    }
}
```

On one panel, I have one listbox (listBoxEmployees) that lists all the employees, and two textboxes giving id and name of the current employee. I have also one listbox (listBoxJobs) that lists all the jobs, one textbox giving the name of the current job as well a combobox used to select an employee for the current job. I would like that the item listed in the comboxbox get populated from the list of employees.
Any Idea how to do that? Thanks a lot for your help.

The code is as follows.

```
 public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();

         var myListOfEmployees = new BindingList<Employee>
        {
            new Employee("Employee1", 1),
            new Employee("Employee2", 2),
            new Employee("Employee3", 3),
        };
        var bindingSourceEmployees = new BindingSource {DataSource = myListOfEmployees};

        var myListOfJobs = new BindingList<Job>
        {
            new Job("Job1",null),
            new Job("Job2", null),
        };
        var bindingSourceJobs = new BindingSource {DataSource = myListOfJobs};

        //Controls Employees
        listBoxEmployees.DataSource = bindingSourceEmployees;
        listBoxEmployees.DisplayMember = "Name";

        textBoxNameEmployee.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceEmployees,
            "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        textBoxIdEmployee.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceEmployees,
            "Id", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);


        //Controls Jobs
        listBoxJobs.DataSource = bindingSourceJobs;
        listBoxJobs.DisplayMember = "Name";

         comboBoxJob.DataSource = myListOfEmployees;
        comboBoxJob.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", bindingSourceJobs, "Employee"));
        comboBoxJob.DisplayMember = "Name";

        textBoxNameJob.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSourceJobs,
            "Name", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
```

Comment: what is your current output and what you expected?

Comment: @MangeshAuti currently the combox does not have any items. I want that it shows the current selected employee for  the current job and that the list of items gets populated with the current list of employees.

Comment: not clear ? can you give some example

Comment: ok for example, here the combo box should list the names of current employees i.e. "Employee1,Employee2,Employee3".

Comment: Currently, you are binding `comboBoxJob` with  `bindingSourceJobs` if you want to bind with Employee then it should be `comboBoxJob.DataSource = bindingSourceEmployees;`

Comment: and then you need to change display member  `comboBoxJob.DisplayMember = "Name";`

Comment: ok thanks but this does not help because if I do that, then when I change the selected employee from the combobox, it changes as well the selected employee from the listBoxEmployees and vice versa. In addition this changes the selected employee for all the jobs.

Comment: then you need to bind with `myListOfEmployees`  try this `comboBoxJob.DataSource = myListOfEmployees;`

Comment: This indeed helps to fill the combo box with the current list of employees but it does not make it possible to specify its own employee for a given job. Indeed here, if I select employee1 for job1,  it selects also employee1 for job2; actually I think the combobox should still be binded to bindingSourceJobs.

Comment: Ok, I finally found something in this post"Binding an enum to a WinForms combo box, and then setting it". I just modified the code, it seems to work.